# Sorting integers inside multiple lists from highest to lowest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in this format: 1st name, last name, wins, losses

alex,kop,5,6

derex,mop,0,11

sas,hot,11,0

rich,john,2,9

jeremy,cane,1,10

My program displays the data from the text file in a leader board only showing players that have won at least 1 game and then calculates their points by multiplying their wins by 3. Here's my code.

```
def points():

template = "|{0:<30}|{1:<30}|{2:<30}|{3:<30}|{4:<30}"
header = template.format("1st name: ","2nd Name: ", "won: ", "lost: ","points: ")

print(header)

with open(r'prac2.txt', 'r') as file:

    for line in file:

        data = line.strip().split(',')

        if int(data[2]) >= 1:

            points = int(data[2]) * 3

            data.append(points)

            print(template.format(*data),'\n')
```

I want to sort the leader board from highest amount of points to lowest amount but i have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin `sorted` with a custom key function:

```
sorted(players, key=lambda player: player.wins * 3 + player.draws)
```

PS: you should save draws, if they can occur ;)

Comment: `sorted` always returns a `list`, since it needs to know all the values. No need to wrap it in a `list`.

Comment: Right, made a mistake here. Thought of map, filter, ....